# NavigateUrl using XSLT

Tags: .net

I've build a menu using XSLT. This is what I did

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
 >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Menus">
    <MenuItems>
        <xsl:call-template name="MenuListing" />
    </MenuItems>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="MenuListing">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Menu" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Menu">
    <MenuItem>
        <!-- Convert Menu child elements to MenuItem attributes -->
        <xsl:attribute name="text">
            <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:attribute name="NavigateUrl">
            <xsl:text>?Sel=</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Url"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <!-- Call MenuListing if there are child Menu nodes -->
        <xsl:if test="count(Menu) > 0">
            <xsl:call-template name="MenuListing" />
        </xsl:if>
    </MenuItem>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And then in Code Behind I would cal it:

```
 if (Request.Params["Sel"] != null)
    Response.Redirect(Request.Params["Sel"], false);
```

The problem is that my url is ~/Default.aspx. So what navigateurl does is it appends ?Sel= to end of default.aspx.  But I need to be forwarded to ~/folder1.aspx(something of this sort) .Can u help in forwarding Url to ~/folder1.aspx

I have a field in databse like Url which has the folder1.aspx.. can u let me know if i can use that..

Answer (score 0):

There must be some JS or aspx code, it is needed to give proper answer. However what about giving absolute path as below.

```
<xsl:text>/folder1.aspx?Sel=</xsl:text>
```

Comment: I have a field in database called Url.But i stored it in this way folder1.aspx.( or folder/folder2.aspx. SO, can u let me know if i can use that  database field?

Comment: concate ur URL to make absolute path Response.Redirect(dr["urlfield"].ToString() + Request.Params["Sel"], false);